# Stata -- output results of ttest

Tags: output, stata

I have data by `group_id` (1,2,3 and so on).  I have to run a t test by `group_id`.  Below I am providing the code I think I will be using for each `group_id`.  How can I modify it so that I can loop over `group_ids` and get an output with all the t tests combined?  Will appreciate any help.  Thanks.

`ttest return, by(test_indicator) unequal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `by` prefix can repeat the t-test for each `group_id`, but it is hard to combine with other codes. Here's a quick example of using `levelsof` and `foreach` to loop through each id, run ttests, and `post` the results to a temporary dataset. The new dataset is then loaded and exported into an .xls file.

```
sysuse auto,clear
recode rep78 (1/3=1)(4/5=2),gen(id) // artificial group id
drop if missing(id) // ensure all casea have ids

tempname ttestparm
tempfile outfile

postfile `ttestparm' obs n1 n2 mu1 mu2 sd1 sd2 diff_b diff_se diff_p using `outfile',replace
levelsof id,local(idvals)
foreach i of local idvals {
    ttest mpg if id==`i', by(foreign)
    post `ttestparm' (`i') (`r(N_1)') (`r(N_2)') (`r(mu_1)') (`r(mu_2)') (`r(sd_1)') (`r(sd_2)') (`r(mu_1)'-`r(mu_2)') (`r(se)') (`r(p)')
}

postclose `ttestparm'
preserve
use `outfile',clear

export excel using "ttestout.xls", firstrow(variables) replace
restore
```

Note that the `preserve`/`restore` combo is only useful if there is more work to do with the original data.

Comment: Defining a local macro and then evaluating it is like putting something in a bag only to take it out immediately afterwards. So just `post` using the macro personas of the r-class results.

Comment: Thanks Aspen Chen.  Your solution worked great for me.  I just added t test to the output.  Very much appreciate your help.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox. I think I thought of running other estimates before `post`. I'll make the revision.

Comment: There's also a small precision loss in pushing through locals rather than scalars, usually inconsequential.