# How to collect / aggregate Stata output from multiple analyses to a file?

Tags: output, stata

I am interested in aggregating / collecting values from analyses in order to output them to a file.  The motivation behind this is to keep the analysis process as much "hands off" as possible so as to avoid typing mistakes and be more efficient in producing results (i.e., not winnowing around a plain text file for a bunch of values and then retyping those into a document...).

As an example, I would like to run three hierarchical regressions, and save the marginal predicted value of SEX on the outcome variable TOTALSCORE.

I know I could start a log file and save all the output, but I would like to avoid having to retype by hand.

I did find a discussion about a similar topic [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489437/stata-output-results-of-ttest), but couldn't figure out how to make it work...

---

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/depression.dta , replace



foreach v of varlist * {
rename `v' `=lower("`v'")'
}
****



anova totalscore i.sex
ereturn list , all
return list , all
estat esize 
return list, all
margins i.sex, at( (mean) _c (asobserved) _f)
return list , all
matrix list r(b)


anova totalscore i.sex i.race
ereturn list , all
estat esize
margins i.sex,  at( (mean) _c (asobserved) _f)
matrix list r(b)



anova totalscore i.sex i.race c.age
ereturn list , all
estat esize
margins i.sex,  at( (mean) _c (asobserved) _f)
matrix list r(b)


/*
would ultimately like to produce something like 
this and save to a file :  


Model       0.sex       1.sex           est_name
model 1     57.237      57.840          anova totalscore i.sex
model 2     57.243      57.825          anova totalscore i.sex  i.race
model 3     57.228      57.864          anova totalscore i.sex  i.race  c.age



*/
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the user-written module `ESTOUT` (run `ssc describe estout`).

An example:

```
clear

use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/depression.dta
rename _all, lower

local mods `" "i.sex" "i.sex i.race" "i.sex i.race c.age" "'

quietly foreach mod of local mods {
    anova totalscore `mod'
    margins i.sex, at( (mean) _c (asobserved) _f) post
    eststo
}   

esttab, noobs not nostar mtitles nonumbers title(Marginal Effects)
eststo clear
```

(Notice the `post` option given to the `margins` command.)

The command allows writing results to file and customizing output in many ways, but **requires thorough reading**.

Answer (score 1):

another answer is given here: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1131792-how-to-collect-aggregate-stata-output-from-multiple-analyses-to-a-file

Comment: I have come full circle to this issue once again.  I ended up using  the `statsby` command to address my problem, and it worked well.